# Transcation already active in python Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, newrelic

We have REST web application handling by Tornado server .

Today I found in log that for some web services I am getting the error `"Transcation already active"  however it is not stopping my any functionality .

Can anyone please suggest me what could be be the reason for this .

Unfortunately I am not able to paste any code snippet here .

Please help me out

Comment: There's no "transaction already active" error message anywhere in Tornado's code, so it must be some other part of your application that's throwing that error, not Tornado. The Python traceback will show you where in the code the error arises.

Comment: Tornado isn't thread-safe in ANY handlers, you have to check database locks/trasactions in your code

Answer (score 0):

For an issue like this you may wish to open a ticket at https://support.newrelic.com